# Angular 2 load child component on click

Tags: angular

Is it possible to load the child component when button in parent template is clicked? For instance, the parent template html would look like:

```
<button (click)="loadMyChildComponent();">Load</button>
<my-child-component></my-child-component>
```

The reason I want to do it like that is because the my-child-component takes some time to load and it slows down everything. Therefore, I'd like to load it only if user clicks to load it. I cannot change the parent template structure. It has to be there.

I want to enter ngOnInit of child's component only when load button is clicked.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use *ngIf directive for the initing component from parent, so your code will be like this

```
<button (click)="loadMyChildComponent();">Load</button>
<my-child-component *ngIf="loadComponent"></my-child-component>

loadMyChildComponent() {
  loadComponent = true;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Make use of flag to control the load of child component.

```
<button (click)="loadMyChildComponent();">Load</button>
<div *ngIf= 'loadComponent'>
<my-child-component></my-child-component>
</div>
```

In your parent component .ts

```
 private loadComponent = false;
    loadMyChildComponent(){
       this.loadComponent = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use perhaps the most fundamental directive [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

```
<button (click)="loadMyChildComponent();">Load</button>
<my-child-component *ngIf="loaded"></my-child-component>
```

In your component

```
loadMyChildComponent(){
 loaded=true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button (click)="loadMyChildComponent()">Load</button>
<div [hidden]="hide">
<my-child-component></my-child-component>
</div>
```

In parent class declare the varible hide and make a function loadMyChildComponent

```
 public hide = true;
  loadMyChildComponent(){
       this.hide= true;
    }
```

Comment: Won't this just load and then hide the component? I don't want it to load before clicking on button

Comment: any how it is going to be loded after clicking the button instead of that load chlid while the parent gets loaded

Comment: @masterfan It wont load your component. You can do console log in `ngOnInit()` and check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular directive [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

`<button (click)="loadChildComponent();">Load Child Component</button>
<child-component *ngIf="childComponentLoaded"></child-component>`

in your component.js

```
public childComponentLoaded: boolean = false;
loadChildComponent() {
    this.childComponentLoaded = true
}
```